# how to do a post to url of pattern /api/{controller}/{action}/{id}?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have my controller method written as follows:

```
public class WorkerController : ApiController
{
    //POST
    //api/worker/unregister/<id>
    //http body:
    //status=<status>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Unregister(int status)        
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Whenever I make a request, it says resource not found (404).

What is the correct way of wiring this?

Edit: wiring the call using PostMan chrome extension - rest client:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/worker/unregister/3
```

...and then I pass post parameters as usual. Its `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Update:

Tried the following:

```
public class WorkerController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public void Unregister(int id, int status)        
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

...and passed the url as below:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/worker/unregister/3?status=-1
```

This worked!

But why didn't the other work. Here is code in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {            

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ServiceApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how you call your method

Comment: @Nilesh added more info

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you have used `status` as parameter name whereas in `WebApiConfig.cs` you have used `id` as parameter name

change your `WebApiConfig.cs` like this

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ServiceApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{status}",
            defaults: new { status = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Apologies. I may have missed out to mention that I needed both `id` and `status` as part of the request somehow. I realize it isn't implied when I mentioned that _I pass post parameters as usual_.

Comment: @deostroll i am not getting you..what you want exactly ? `route` with both `id` and `status` as parameter

Comment: Not `route`. I wanted it part of the `http request` somehow. Not sure if its possible to get both values into the `route`. What I've learned is that the `route` gives me value for `id` (because that how I have configured it), and unless I have a corresponding model to capture `status` (which I am passing as http body), I cannot get the value of `status`. Hence you need a model in your action's definition.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I figured it out!

**You have to pass a model.**

```
public class fooModel
{
    public int status {get; set;}
}
```

The action should be re-written as follows:

```
public void unregister(int id, fooModel m)
{
    Debug.Print(m.status);
}
```